# JSON-LD Frame: framed object properties as term only (not as IRI)

Tags: parsing, json-ld

I'm learning how to use JSON-LD frames using Node *jsonld.js*, and I'm wondering why some properties are labeled as IRI whereas others are labeled as terms, and I can't see no obvious reason for that difference.

Here's the [sample](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab0%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRecording%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FbyArtist%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Paper'd%20Up%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2FPaper%2527d-Up%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2FPaper%2527d-Up%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fduration%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22PT3M55S%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fimage%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_200%2Flr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FinAlbum%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fproducer%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab3%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FthumbnailUrl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_100%2Fmr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicGroup%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Snoop%20Dogg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicAlbum%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FalbumRelease%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab4%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Paid%20the%20Cost%20to%20Be%20the%20Bo%24%24%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab3%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FPerson%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Fredwreck%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FFredwreck%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FFredwreck%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab4%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicRelease%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FdatePublished%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%222001%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FrecordLabel%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Priority%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab5%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRecording%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FbyArtist%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab6%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Don't%20Look%20Any%20Further%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2FDon%2527t-Look-Any-Further%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2FDon%2527t-Look-Any-Further%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fduration%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22PT4M00S%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fimage%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_200%2Flr2_20081121_22647244200.jpg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FinAlbum%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab7%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fproducer%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab8%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FthumbnailUrl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_100%2Fmr2_20081121_22647244200.jpg%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab6%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicGroup%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Dennis%20Edwards%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab7%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicAlbum%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FalbumRelease%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab9%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Don't%20Look%20Any%20Further%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab8%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FPerson%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Dennis%20Edwards%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab9%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FMusicRelease%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FdatePublished%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%221984%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.schema.org%2FrecordLabel%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Gordy%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fdocs%2Fjsonldcontext.json%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22MusicRecording%22%5D%7D).

For example, in that sample, the `name` property is labeled as expected, whereas in other cases it's labeled as `http://www.schema.org/name`, same with `url` and `http://www.schema.org/url`; and I can't figure out why:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "id": "_:b0",
      "type": "MusicRecording",
      "byArtist": {
        "id": "_:b1",
        "type": "http://www.schema.org/MusicGroup",
        "http://www.schema.org/name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "http://www.schema.org/sameAs": "/Snoop-Dogg/"
      },
      "name": "Paper'd Up",
      "schema:sameAs": "/Snoop-Dogg/Paper%27d-Up/",
      "url": "../Snoop-Dogg/Paper%27d-Up/",
      "http://www.schema.org/duration": "PT3M55S",
      "http://www.schema.org/image": "/static/track_images_200/lr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg",
      "http://www.schema.org/inAlbum": {
        "id": "_:b2",
        "type": "http://www.schema.org/MusicAlbum",
        "http://www.schema.org/albumRelease": {
          "id": "_:b4",
          "type": "http://www.schema.org/MusicRelease",
          "http://www.schema.org/datePublished": "2001",
          "http://www.schema.org/recordLabel": "Priority"
        },
        "http://www.schema.org/name": "Paid the Cost to Be the Bo$$"
      },
      "http://www.schema.org/producer": {
        "id": "_:b3",
        "type": "http://www.schema.org/Person",
        "http://www.schema.org/name": "Fredwreck",
        "http://www.schema.org/sameAs": "/Fredwreck/",
        "http://www.schema.org/url": {
          "id": "../Fredwreck/"
        }
      },
      "http://www.schema.org/thumbnailUrl": {
        "id": "../static/track_images_100/mr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to retrieve the tree with properties named as type instead of IRI (using *jsonld.js*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's necessary that the term match the IRI you use for the property. For example, schema.org defines `name` as `http://schema.org/name`. In your example, you have `http://www.schema.org/name`.

There are also several places where values which should be IRIs (URLs) are treated as text, for this you want to use something like `"http://schema.org/image": {"@id": "/static/track_images_200/lr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg"}`

Part of term selection looks to be sure that a value matches the appropriate `@type` definition within the context. For example, `image` is set to `{"@type": "@id"}`, so it will only match things that look like that.

Here's an [updated example on the playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab0%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRecording%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FbyArtist%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Paper'd%20Up%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2FPaper%2527d-Up%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2FPaper%2527d-Up%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fduration%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22PT3M55S%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fimage%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_200%2Flr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FinAlbum%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fproducer%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab3%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FthumbnailUrl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_100%2Fmr1734_2009720_1372375126.jpg%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicGroup%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Snoop%20Dogg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FSnoop-Dogg%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicAlbum%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FalbumRelease%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab4%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Paid%20the%20Cost%20to%20Be%20the%20Bo%24%24%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab3%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Fredwreck%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FFredwreck%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FFredwreck%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab4%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRelease%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FdatePublished%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%222001%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FrecordLabel%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Priority%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab5%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRecording%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FbyArtist%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab6%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Don't%20Look%20Any%20Further%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2FDon%2527t-Look-Any-Further%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2FDon%2527t-Look-Any-Further%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fduration%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22PT4M00S%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fimage%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_200%2Flr2_20081121_22647244200.jpg%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FinAlbum%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab7%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fproducer%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab8%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FthumbnailUrl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2Fstatic%2Ftrack_images_100%2Fmr2_20081121_22647244200.jpg%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab6%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicGroup%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Dennis%20Edwards%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab7%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicAlbum%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FalbumRelease%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab9%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Don't%20Look%20Any%20Further%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab8%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Dennis%20Edwards%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FsameAs%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Furl%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22%2FDennis-Edwards%2F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab9%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FMusicRelease%22%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FdatePublished%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%221984%22%7D%5D%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FrecordLabel%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40value%22%3A%22Gordy%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fdocs%2Fjsonldcontext.json%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22MusicRecording%22%5D%7D).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Actually, the data is extracted from [WhoSampled](https://www.whosampled.com/sample/26198/Snoop-Dogg-Paper'd-Up-Dennis-Edwards-Siedah-Garrett-Don't-Look-Any-Further/) using _[microdata-node:toJsonld/1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microdata-node)_, and `SchemaOrg` reference is not always consistent, e.g.: `itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicRecording"` and `itemtype="http://www.schema.org/MusicGroup"`.

Is there any strategy to normalize SchemaOrg URIs ? Or should I regex them before parsing ? Perhaps _microdata-node_ `config.registry` option might be used.

Comment: _Addendum_: How to handle these for 4 potential cases : `http://schema.org`, `https://schema.org`, `http://www.schema.org` and `https://www.schema.org` ? I've come across those 4 cases though, and have no idea at which level this differences should be handled and how to deal with them.

Comment: As URLs for retrieving resources, they may all be fine. But for the namespace of the defined terms, they must all be in http://schema.org/. Not sure about the node tool you’re using, but there is also a standard for turning Microdata into RDF, but if the source data is wrong, that might not help.

Comment: Well, testing with [RDF Distiller](https://rdf-translator.appspot.com/convert/microdata/json-ld/https://www.whosampled.com/sample/26198/Snoop-Dogg-Paper'd-Up-Dennis-Edwards-Siedah-Garrett-Don't-Look-Any-Further/) not all properties are caught, whereas the [Google Structure Data testing tools](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https://www.whosampled.com/sample/26198/Snoop-Dogg-Paper'd-Up-Dennis-Edwards-Siedah-Garrett-Don't-Look-Any-Further/) doesn't yield any error or warning, and is able to catch all properties. Does the Google tool result look compliant with the spec?